# Elasticsearch RestClient Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have in my AWS VPC a cluster of ES with 2 nodes. On top of those nodes I have a load balancer. In the same vpc I have a microservice that accesses Elasticsearch via `RestHighLevelClient` version 7.5.2 .

I create the client in the following manner :

```
public class ESClientWrapper {

    @Getter
    private RestHighLevelClient client;

    public ESClientWrapper() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream propertiesFile = new FileInputStream("/var/elastic.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(propertiesFile );
        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(
                properties .getProperty("host"),
                Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("port"))
        ));

        this.client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
    }
}
```

When my micro service doesn't get requests for a long time (12h..) there are occurrences when the first response that is sent (or a few after..) are getting the following error:

```
    2020-09-09 07:03:13.106  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.a.services.CustomersMetadataService  : Trying to add the following role : {role=a2}
2020-09-09 07:03:13.106  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.a.e.repositories.ESRepository        : Trying to insert the following document to app-index : {role=a2}
2020-09-09 07:03:13.109 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.a.e.dal.ESRepository       : Failed to add customer : {role=a2}


java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:828) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.5.2.jar!/:7.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:248) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.5.2.jar!/:7.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:235) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.5.2.jar!/:7.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1514) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.5.2.jar!/:7.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1484) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.5.2.jar!/:7.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1454) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.5.2.jar!/:7.5.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.index(RestHighLevelClient.java:871) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.5.2.jar!/:7.5.2]
    ....
    ....
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:245) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:358) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionInputBufferImpl.fill(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:231) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.13.jar!/:4.4.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.fillBuffer(AbstractMessageParser.java:136) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.13.jar!/:4.4.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:241) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.13.jar!/:4.4.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.4.jar!/:4.1.4]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.4.jar!/:4.1.4]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.13.jar!/:4.4.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.13.jar!/:4.4.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.13.jar!/:4.4.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.13.jar!/:4.4.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.13.jar!/:4.4.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.13.jar!/:4.4.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.13.jar!/:4.4.13]
        ... 1 common frames omitted

2020-09-09 07:06:55.109  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.a.a.services.MyService  : Trying to add the following role : {role=a2}
2020-09-09 07:06:55.109  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.a.a.e.repositories.ESRepository        : Trying to insert the following document to index app-index: {role=a2}
2020-09-09 07:06:55.211  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.a.a.e.dal.ESRepository       : IndexResponse[index=app-index,type=_doc,id=x532323272533321870287,version=1,result=created,seqNo=70,primaryTerm=1,shards={"total":2,"successful":2,"failed":0}]
```

As you can see, 3 minutes after the failed request the next request was successfully handeled by ES. What can kill the request ? I checked Elasticsearch logs and didn't see any indication for killing connection. The MS is in the same vpc as elastic so it isn't passing through any firewall that might kill it.

I found the [following issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/44546) in github that suggested to increase the default connection timeout but I'm wondering if the issue here is really a timeout problem and if increasing the default time is really the best solution..

Also, I found [this bug](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/60450) opened in their repo regarding the same problem but without any answers.

**UPDATE**
I noticed that even after 10 minutes my service is up this happens. My service started and sent a query to ES and everything worked well. After 10 minutes I sent insert request and it failed on connection reset by peer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I didn't find a problem in my configuration/implementation. It seems like a [bug](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/60450) in the implementation of Elasticsearch's RestHighLevelClient.

I implemented a retry mechanism that wraps the RestHighLevelClient and retries the query if I get the same error. I used Spring @Retry annotation for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. Everything worked fine, but after some time a single request got refused.

The solution (in my case) was to set the keepalive property of the tcp connection with:

```
final RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(...);
    
restClientBuilder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder.setDefaultIOReactorConfig(IOReactorConfig.custom()
                                .setSoKeepAlive(true)
                                .build()))
```

Found here:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/65213